# Props not passing to component React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components, react-props

I'm trying to clean up my code and have moved a large chunk into it's own component, although now nothing is rendering in the component I've moved, and the props aren't passing through to my MovieComponent.

app.js:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./App.css";
import styled from "styled-components";
import movieicon1 from "./icons/movieicon1.png";
import MovieComponent from "./components/MovieComponent";
import api from "./api/Api";

const Container = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
`;
const Header = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  background-color: black;
  justify-content: space-between;
  color: white;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: bold;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 6px 0 #555;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
`;
const AppName = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
`;
const MovieImage = styled.img`
  width: 48px;
  height: 48px;
  margin: 15px;
`;
const MovieListContainer = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding: 30px;
  gap: 24px;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
`;
function App() {


  const [error, setError] = useState(false);

  return (
    <Container>
      <Header>
        <AppName>
          <MovieImage src={movieicon1} />
          Prince's Theatre
        </AppName>
      </Header>
      {error ? <div>Oops there seems to be a problem please refresh</div> : ""}

      <MovieListContainer>
        
          <MovieComponent />
       
      </MovieListContainer>
    </Container>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I've moved the majority of code into my MovieListContainer:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useMemo } from "react";
import MovieComponent from "./MovieComponent";
import api from "../api/Api";

function MovieListContainer() {
  const [error, setError] = useState(false);
  const [filmWorld, setFilmWorld] = useState([]);
  const [cinemaWorld, setCinemaWorld] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    const theaters = ["cinema", "film"];
    theaters.forEach((theater) => {
      async function getTheater() {
        const data = await api.getMoviesData(theater);
        if (data == null) {
          setError(true);
          return;
        }
        if (data.Provider === "Film World") {
          setFilmWorld(data);
        } else {
          setCinemaWorld(data);
        }
      }
      getTheater();
    });
  }, []);

  const movies = useMemo(() => {
    if (!filmWorld.Provider) return [];
    return filmWorld.Movies.map((movie, index) => ({
      ...movie,
      cinemaWorldPrice:
        cinemaWorld.Provider && cinemaWorld.Movies[index]?.Price,
    }));
  }, [filmWorld, cinemaWorld]);

  return movies.map((movie, index) => (
    <MovieComponent key={index} movie={movie} error={error} />
  ));
}

export default MovieListContainer;
```

and from here it seems that the props aren't making it to my MovieComponent:

```
import React from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";
import PriceCheckIcon from "@mui/icons-material/PriceCheck";
import CurrencyFormat from "react-currency-format";

const MovieContainer = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 280px;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 10px 0 #aaa;
  cursor: pointer;
`;
const CoverImage = styled.img`
  height: 362px;
`;
const MovieName = styled.span`
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: black;
  margin: 15px 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
`;
const InfoColumn = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: flex-end;
`;
const MovieInfo = styled.span`
  font-size: 18x;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: black
  text-transform: capitalize;
  
`;

const MovieComponent = (props) => {
  const { Poster, Price, Title, cinemaWorldPrice } = props.movie;
  const { error } = props;
  return (
    <MovieContainer data-testid="movieComponent-1">
      <CoverImage src={Poster} alt="" />
      <MovieName>{Title}</MovieName>

      <InfoColumn>
        <MovieInfo>
          FilmWorld: &nbsp;
          <span
            style={
              Price < cinemaWorldPrice ? { color: "green" } : { color: "red" }
            }
          >
            <CurrencyFormat
              value={Price}
              displayType={"text"}
              prefix={"$"}
              decimalScale={2}
              fixedDecimalScale
            />
          </span>
        </MovieInfo>
        <MovieInfo>
          CinemaWorld: &nbsp;
          <span
            style={
              Price > cinemaWorldPrice ? { color: "green" } : { color: "red" }
            }
          >
            {error === "Server Error" && Price > cinemaWorldPrice ? (
              <PriceCheckIcon />
            ) : (
              <CurrencyFormat
                value={cinemaWorldPrice}
                displayType={"text"}
                prefix={"$"}
                decimalScale={2}
                fixedDecimalScale
              />
            )}
          </span>
        </MovieInfo>
      </InfoColumn>
    </MovieContainer>
  );
};

export default MovieComponent;
```

Comment: Install the React Developer Tools extension for Chrome/Firefox and inspect your app. You can see each component's props&state. Probably a simple typo type mistake, and should be easy to spot.

Comment: @ChrisG I don't think it's a typo I've just copied and pasted functioning code.

Comment: You have a prop-free `<MovieComponent />` inside your App's `<MovieListContainer>` that doesn't belong there so my guess is typo type error in the sense of "simply mistake that is easy to find"

Comment: @ChrisG thanks, I have removed it and still am not getting the props to go to the MovieComponent

Comment: Does that mean you're seeing a bunch of basically blank <MovieComponent />s? Have you done any debugging yet? Like console.log()s?